# How to display paperclip's uploads.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Im currently building a blog. While the paperclip photos pop up inside the individual blog posts they don't seem to pop up in the index, where all the blog posts are displayed. 
13th line seems to be the problem.

this is my index.html.erb for my posts

```
10   <% @posts.each do |post| %>
11       <tr>
12       <td><%= link_to  post.title, post_path(post) %></td>
13       <td><%= image_tag @post.picture(:medium) %></td>
14       <td><%= post.text %></td>
15       <td><%= link_to 'Show', action: :show, id: post.id %></td>
16       <td><%= link_to 'Edit', action: :edit, id: post.id %></td>
17       <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', { action: :destroy, id: post.id },
18                       method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

it throws me a no method error.

Please let me know if I can give you extra files if you need more information
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing the URL for the image to the `image_tag` helper.

You need to display your image like this:

```
<%= image_tag post.picture.url(:medium) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access the `@post` instance variable, but that instance variable doesn't exist. Rather, within your loop, you should access your `post` local variable as such:

```
<%= image_tag post.picture.url(:medium) %>
```

Note also that, from [the documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#show-view), the correct syntax to access variations of a `Picture` instance involves passing the variation name to the `url` attribute:

```
post.picture(:medium) # Invalid
post.picture.url(:medium) # Valid!
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Jon, you need to use the `.url` method on your `picture` object ([official documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#show-view)):

```
<%= image_tag post.picture.url(:medium) %>
```

---

**Paperclip**

The reason for this is Paperclip actually creates its own `picture` object & attaches several methods to that (`url` being one of them). This means you have to call `url` each time you show the post's image to get it to load

Normally, you'd be able to call methods on your instance or local variables, but as Paperclip actually creates its own object, you have to use its in-built methods to get it to work correctly